# Display Suite Code Field does not display on node

Tags: theming, tokens, display-suite

I'm trying to manipulate a field in display suite on a test site, but the field is not displaying in DS format. Is there anything I need to link or enable in order to use this format?

Comment: DS in drupal 7??

Comment: Yes, this I am trying to implement on D7

Comment: can you please elaborate more on what you want to achieve